Read .dat files from old Delphi application
I'm a PHP+JS developer, I know nothing about Delphi.
I have a 20 year old application that is a booking server/client application made with Delphi + SQL (this is a working application, but the developer does not exist anymore). In the same folder as the executable file I have a lot of .dat files that are named like DB tables (cities.dat, ports.dat, availability.dat, etc.).
I'm trying to get some data from these .dat files that I suppose are some kind of local database files, but I don't know how to open these files. For sure, they are not plain text files. Any suggestions?
Essentially I need to fetch the cities.dat and availability.dat for connecting with another application.
This is the first initial 256 bytes of a file:

F1 F4 45 0B  F3 FA 98 80  9A FC 8F 75  9F 1E 27 9C  ..E. .... ...u ..'. 
71 79 E0 6B  60 B9 45 A3  8C 63 75 88  AC 57 81 8A  qy.k `.E. .cu. .W..
EB BC 56 45  A2 9B 5B 13  2F 1D 6A 69  47 F4 08 5E  ..VE ..k. /.ji G..^
CC 29 A7 33  A0 A7 49 9D  B6 CB 73 D5  5F B7 43 4D  .).3 ..I. ..s. _.CM
82 05 23 49  5B 37 7D 02  E7 BD 85 87  D9 57 E9 6B  ..#I [7}. .... .W.k
79 71 68 3F  FD 7E CB BD  03 C9 DA E2  CA B5 DD B9  yqh? .~.. .... ....
77 2E 2F 46  F0 E6 86 7E  E0 DF B0 47  22 B1 AD B7  w./F ...~ ...G "...
39 BC 0A 31  70 95 75 8E  BC 34 D6 2C  9E 7C 3D DF  9..1 p.u. .4., .|=.


further inspecting with IDR I found some classes that are building the data structure, seems that relies to "Data abstract for Delphi" that is using some kind of serialization library named TDABin2DataStreamer to store and read the data in a propetary bin format. Honestly I tried everything to import this library in a shell delphi project to deserialize these .dat files, but I could not find a way to make this to works, I always receive errors about missing libraries, but I'm sure that all paths of Data abstract libraries are included.

Without knowing any information about how the files were created, the layout of the files, what kind of database engine the app uses, etc, it will be pretty hard to explain how to read data out of the files. Unless you have the source code for the app, you may have to resort to (finding someone who can) reverse engineer the app/files to figure out how they work.

Load the file in a hex editor and quote its first 256 bytes. Its first bytes might already match one of the major known signatures. Did your software exist as download in the past? Then asking Wayback for the old website might bring up format explanations, too.

These files can be anything; my guess is the format was determined by the developers at the time. See also 'How do you open a DAT file when you don't know what's in it?' in https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dat-file-how-to-open-the-dat-file-format-extension/ I suggest you try Notepad(++) or a hex editor and see what the first 100-200 bytes suggest. You can [edit] that info in your question for others to look at.

Also, Google for DAT file extension

@AmigoJack I edited the question, the software is custom software made for our company 16years ago, I'm sure is made with Delphi and I know that the db connection is SQL

The problem is that a .dat file does not follow any standard, and your data shows no readable ascii. It could be anything at all.

A 16 years old Delphi application that works with a database would most likely use Borland Database Engine (BDE). But on the other hand back in the days many Delphi developers actually made their own custom databases that were storing their data in files by using old File Input and Output Support like Database: file of TMyRecord; where TMyRecord is simply a fixed sized Delphi record.

DBISAM uses .dat files, but there are also index files with .idx extensions.  Do you have any design-time components that reference these files?

The db connection is SQL - that isn't true, or meaningful. SQL is a query language. It doesn't contain data. SQL is pure text. The fact that the app is made in Delphi is also meaningless. The file content is simply binary, and without a definition of the file format that you can use, you're out of luck. .dat is an arbitrary file extension. It was used by both Paradox and Btrieve as an extension, but it has also been used by others, and for content that is not a database.

Copyright strings in the executable or DLLs loaded by it often reference companies and products which can give some indication of what database was used. For example a (C)XXXX TurboPower would likely mean it used FlashFiler.

You didn't say which file you showed an example of.  If you look in cities.dat, for example, can you see the names of cities?  If you can, how many bytes apart does each city name start?  If it's always the same number of bytes, then SilverWarrior's suggestion of a file of TMyRecord might be correct.  That won't solve your problem, but could be a small step in the right direction.

@KenWhite yes you are right, further inspecting the folder I found a tdbd file so I suppose is a turbodb file but I still get errors, I updated the original question with some screenshots of the error

Don't post screenshots of text - message box content can easily be copied to clipboard pressing Ctrl+C. Text in pictures cannot be found by others who search for similar issues.

errors about missing libraries where? at compile time? at runtime? Do you see any readable text at all in the data files that correlates to the data displayed by the executable? Does the executable allow for editing?  If so, copy a data file and change something so that its AAAAAAAA to the maximum size of the field and then compare the differences. Try again with an empty field (if possible) and compare again.  This might help you identify how the field is being stored.  There might be some data forensic tools that might help as well if it is just RLE encoded or uses simple compression.

You can open the executable in IDR to see its forms and the components used.
see the answers to this question: Is there a program to decompile Delphi?
The programs listed in the answers can help you to see the components used to create the database files as well as their properties.
This should allow you to see what database variant was used and from there perhaps decipher the file format.

I updated the answer after inspecting with IDR as you suggested
